# No. of partitions of $m$ with bounded $k$ parts

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $\bar{n} = (n_1,\dots, n_k)$ be a fixed tuple of positive integers. Define $\mathcal P_m ({\bar{n}}) $ to be the set of all partitions of $m$  with exactly $k$ parts and the i-th part is bounded by $n_i$.

How to find the cardinality of the set $\mathcal P_m ({\bar{n}}) $?

Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Two big questions that needs to be answered: (1) Is $\overline{n}$ requires to be made of *distinct* $n_i$? (2) Does order matter? For example, take $\overline{n}= \{3,5,2,5\}$. Is $\{1,2,1,1\}$ the same as $\{1,1,1,2\}$? And are those two the same as $\{2,1,1,1\}$? ---- Also I want to say that just the problem of partitioning into exactly $k$ parts is mildly difficult; this count seems likely to be extremely difficult.

Comment: @EricSnyder (1) $\bar{n}$ need not be distinct in my case. (2) Yes. Order Matters. (Does it means that should I consider the compositions?) In my case, the partitions $\{1,2,1,1\}$ and $\{1,1,1,2\}$ are distinct. Thank you.